# Polars Lazyframe Left join and ~is_in filter not working as expected

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars, lazyframe

When I use lazyframe and use left join along with ~is_in filter, nulls are created instead of dropping the rows. This happens in lazyframe but not in eager

```
pl_df = pl.DataFrame({
        "group":["A","B","C","D","E","F"],
        "values": [1,2,None,4,5,6],
        "values1":[1,2,None,4,5,6],
        "values2":[1,2,None,4,5,6]
})

pl_df2 = pl_df.lazy()
pl_df3=(
    pl_df2.select(pl.exclude("group"))
    .join(pl_df.lazy(),
        left_on="values",right_on="values2",how="left")
        )

a = pl_df3.collect().shape

b = pl_df3.filter(~pl.col("group").is_in(["D","E","F"])).collect().shape
```

b rows are expected to be less than number of rows in a. But the output shows same number of rows for both a and b

Comment: I think this is a bug and created a github issue for it 
https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10193

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the effect of predicate pushdown. When you're using the lazy evaluator it optimizes the entire query plan before it actually computes it. That means that although you chained the `filter` on last, it will push that down to all the operations. In that way it filters out `["D","E","F"]` from all the inputs before it does the expensive work of actually joining them all. Since you're doing a left join it still returns the rows.

There are two things you can do:

1. You can specify `predicate_pushdown=False` inside of your `collect`

```
(pl_df3
    .filter(~pl.col("group").is_in(["D","E","F"]))
    .collect(predicate_pushdown=False))
shape: (3, 6)
┌────────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ values ┆ values1 ┆ values2 ┆ group ┆ values_right ┆ values1_right │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---          ┆ ---           │
│ i64    ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ str   ┆ i64          ┆ i64           │
╞════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═══════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1      ┆ 1       ┆ 1       ┆ A     ┆ 1            ┆ 1             │
│ 2      ┆ 2       ┆ 2       ┆ B     ┆ 2            ┆ 2             │
│ null   ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ C     ┆ null         ┆ null          │
└────────┴─────────┴─────────┴───────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘
```

2. You can change your join to `how='inner'`

```
(pl_df2.select(pl.exclude("group"))
    .join(pl_df.lazy(),
        left_on="values",right_on="values2",how="inner")
    .filter(~pl.col("group").is_in(["D","E","F"]))
    .collect())
shape: (3, 6)
┌────────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ values ┆ values1 ┆ values2 ┆ group ┆ values_right ┆ values1_right │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---          ┆ ---           │
│ i64    ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ str   ┆ i64          ┆ i64           │
╞════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═══════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1      ┆ 1       ┆ 1       ┆ A     ┆ 1            ┆ 1             │
│ 2      ┆ 2       ┆ 2       ┆ B     ┆ 2            ┆ 2             │
│ null   ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ C     ┆ null         ┆ null          │
└────────┴─────────┴─────────┴───────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: Note as of polars 0.18.10 (today) this is now fixed with an explicit blocking of `predicate_pushdown`:  https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/10194